# Which API service can I use for my music application?

Tags: api, spotify

I want to create my own music app so that people can listen to music through the app as recordings. I've done some research, but many sites that provide API services allow users to listen to recordings from their own sites. How can I cause users to listen to music without having to record from other sites by making my own music app?

I have looked at several sites that offer API services, but most of them allow users to listen to music by recording through their own system. However, I am planning to allow users to listen to music without recording through a third-party company.

Comment: Spotify doesn't allow third-party apps to stream music anymore. (reason for my comment: the Spotify tag)

Comment: So what do you think I can use?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.